# Are there any advantages for std::string_view over char* other than the std::string_view methods?

Tags: c++, refactoring, c++17, c-strings, string-view

Are there any advantages for std::string_view over char* other than the std::string_view methods?

Are there any reasons to re-factor `char*` into `string_view` if none of `string_view`'s methods would be used?

Comment: Here's a few of many reasons: `char*` requires a call to `strlen`, which is O(n), whereas `string_view` can give you the length in constant time (oh wait, but this is part of `std::string_view`'s methods). `string_view` can refer to non-null-terminated strings, `char*` cannot usually. The list can go on and on.

Comment: As usual with broad questions like this, the answer is, "It depends" - specificially, "on what you need to do."

Answer (score 9):

A `char*` is just a pointer to a character.  For it to be interpreted as a string you need a length, either explicit (pascal strings store it before the first character, or you could pass length information beside it as another argument or struct member), or implicitly (null termination).

A string view is an abstraction of the 2nd of the above.  Unlike the 1st or 3rd, it does not require data contiguous to the string buffer to contain length information.  This means you can create non-owning substrings in O(1) time without copying, something the other two approaches cannot do.

Determining the length of a string for 1st and 2nd case above is O(1) and O(n) for null termination.  This matters.

The string view has no fundamental advantages over a pair of `char*` or a `char*` paired with a length; all you gain compared to those is the utility methods.  But it is fundamentally different than a null terminated char buffer.

Comment: Or to put it simply, `char*` is an iterator; `string_view` is a *range*.

Comment: The last para is the clearest: `std::string_view` is like a `char*, char*`  or `char*,length`  wrapped in an abstraction with some helpful methods. 

I feel `std::string_view` is what everyone realised they needed, after they discovered that using `std::sting` everywhere they used to use `char*` in `C`, was far too heavy and resulted in far too much copying (or bending over backwards to prevent it).